# Testing a system call in qemu

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, kernel, qemu

I have just started to look into the *Linux kernel development*. I have a kernel image ***bzimage*** and an ***initrd*** which works fine on **qemu**. Now I have compiled the kernel after adding a new sys call to it. I want to test the system call on qemu what is the preferred way of doing this, (if any) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[syscall()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html) function in unistd.h can be used.

Refer the following blog which does exactly same.
http://linuxseekernel.blogspot.ie/2014/07/adding-system-call-in-x86-qemu.html